# Getting image coordinates from xml

Tags: c#, xml, image

I have an .xml file which contains this:

```
<a:xfrm>
<a:off x="381000" y="152400"/>
<a:ext cx="2124075" cy="2162175"/>
</a:xfrm>
```

These are image's coordinates. In .Net, I want to show that image with C#, in wpf app. I do that with the BitmapImage class. The image is shown, but its size isn't correct. Can I find out the coordinates from the numbers of x, cx, y and cy above?

This is a bigger part of the xml:

```
<p:pic>
    <p:nvPicPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1026" name="Picture 2" descr="C:\Users\John\Desktop\images.jpg"/>
        <p:cNvPicPr>
                    <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
        </p:cNvPicPr>
    <p:nvPr/>
</p:nvPicPr>
<p:blipFill>
    <a:blip r:embed="rId2" cstate="print"/>
    <a:srcRect/>
    <a:stretch>
    <a:fillRect/>
    </a:stretch>
</p:blipFill>
<p:spPr bwMode="auto">
    <a:xfrm>
        <a:off x="381000" y="152400"/>
        <a:ext cx="2124075" cy="2162175"/>
    </a:xfrm>
    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
    <a:avLst/>
    </a:prstGeom>
    <a:noFill/>
    </p:spPr>
</p:pic>
```

Comment: How does your code that crops the image looks like? Are cx and cy offset or absolute values?

Comment: The xml isn't generated by me.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the pptx is converted to xml like that, nothing is changed by code or by me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070074/how-can-i-retrieve-images-from-a-pptx-file-using-ms-open-xml-sdk

Comment: @L.B No, that doesn't help me, it gets the slide size, not the image size.

Comment: @user966638 I thought you could use the *magic* numbers in that question to calc. your image size (something like cx/12700)

Comment: It gives me the original size. But if I multily it by 0.7, the size is ok. That's because of the zoom in the pptx. But, how to get 0.7 from the xml?

Comment: @L.B the link helped :) Can you answer the question so that I can choose your answer as the best?

Comment: @L.B the link helped :) Can you answer the question so that I can choose your answer as the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a another question related to it. [How can I retrieve images from a .pptx file using MS Open XML SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070074/how-can-i-retrieve-images-from-a-pptx-file-using-ms-open-xml-sdk)
Maybe You can use the magic numbers in that question to calc. your image size (something like cx/12700)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert these values to pixels using these formulas, I think...

Where VALUE is the value you want to convert. I think Felice Pollano probably has the correct method for dealing with it after that. I hope I understand your needs correctly.

```
horizontalPixels = (VALUE * horizontalResolutionInDPI) / 914400
verticalPixels = (VALUE * verticalResolutionInDPI) / 914400
```

VALUE is the value provided in the XML. horizontalPixels is the actual width of the image in pixels and the horizontalResolutionInDPI is the DPI of the image.

Comment: I tried and I get really big values. It doesn't give me the real size.

Comment: Can you give us indication of the real size?

Comment: The real size doesn't correspond to the xml. The original size corresponds to the xml, but when I change the size of the image in the pptx file, I only change the zoom of the image, not the size. So, if the image has width of 150 and height of 150, and I resize it, the xml changes but the width and height of the image don't change. Its zoom changes.

Comment: One more thing, in the code I wrote image.width = cx-x;, is that what you were thinking?

Comment: In my case, what is value, what is horizontalResolutionInDPI and what is horizontalPixels?

Comment: VALUE is the value provided in the XML. horizontalPixels is the actual width of the image in pixels and the horizontalResolutionInDPI is the DPI of the image. I do not know if there is an easy way for you to find the DPI... Might just be a case of getting hold of one of the images somehow and getting that manually.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to scale. First find the boundary, we just need to know *what* is cx, I suppose is the center of the placement of the shape, so just collect all coordinates in both direction: this mean `cx+x,cy+y, cx-x,cy -y`, and finding the min x,min y,max x/max y. When you have this information you can calculate a scaling factor by diving your image size width or height per the X or Y max value you calculated. Then before draw multiply all ypour coordinates by this factor. You should choose to calc the scale in just one X or Y to mantain the image aspect.

Comment: This doesn't work either. The values I get are too big, and the image is small.

Comment: try to post the code you are using to computhe the scale. Try to specify better what is x and cx

Comment: cx+x = 7467600 - max x;
cy+y = 4940809 - max y;
cx-x = -5638800 - min x;
cy -y = -3136393 - min y;

i don't know what is cx or x, because I don't create the xml, it's generated automaticaly from .pptx file.

Comment: well you have to investigate what is cx cy ( I guess the center of some shape, but just guessing ) then you have to divide not tu subtract in order to retrieve the scale factor... I think you need to read something before trying to solve that problem.

Comment: Ok, if the zoom in the .pptx file is 70%, that means that the scaling factor is 0.7. But, if I get unknown .pptx, how to get the scaling factor? I searched on the internet and got nothing. I don't know how to investigate after that.